# No command 'apt' found, did you mean:

Tags: apt

When I try to run:

```
apt –get install vsftpd
```

I get the error:

```
No command 'apt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'aptd' from package 'aptdaemon' (main)
 Command 'xapt' from package 'xapt' (universe)
 Command 'opt' from package 'llvm' (universe)
 Command 'apm' from package 'apmd' (main)
 Command 'atp' from package 'atp' (universe)
 Command 'ppt' from package 'bsdgames' (universe)
 Command 'apf' from package 'apf-firewall' (universe)
 Command 'apg' from package 'apg' (main)
 Command 'gpt' from package 'gpt' (universe)
 Command 'ant' from package 'ant' (main)
 Command 'ant' from package 'ant1.7' (universe)
 Command 'at' from package 'at' (main)
 Command 'pat' from package 'dist' (universe)
 Command 'aft' from package 'aft' (universe)
apt: command not found
```

What gives? -.-

Comment: the command is 'apt-get' plus the option 'install' and then the package name. So no space in 'apt-get'

Answer (score 5):

Try running

```
apt-get install vsftpd
```

There shouldn't be a space after the **"apt"** ...

Answer (score 3):

As stated, the correct command is `apt-get`. However, you are more than likely going to need to sudo install it as the root user.. so if installing doesn't work, try `sudo apt-get install vfghty` and enter your password when it asks. Hopefull that works, good luck!

Comment: absolutely correct, installing any program with the possible exception of .sh files that only install in your local /home directory WILL need to be preceded by `sudo`. all apt-get commands will fail if not `sudo`

Comment: I was logged in as root.  But that is a very good tip.  Thanks!!

Comment: @Amy BTW it is a bad idea to log in as root, it can change the permissions of files if used in your home directory, I believe that there are other issues as well.  Using `sudo` is the preferred way to execute commands that need root privileges as these problems are avoided.

Comment: @TrailRider Right, `apt-get -s ...` is a simulation (which will generally succeed when run as a non-`root` user because it doesn't modify packages on the system). To change what's installed or systemwide information about it with `apt-get`, you do need to use `sudo`.